# What is the best & worst time complexity Of KMP algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, knuth-morris-pratt

Need clarification on the best time complexity & the worst time complexity of KMP algorithm. The thing that is confusing to me is the worst search time complexity of O(n). What I understood after reading online is that there are two indexes. One index i is for text & another index j is for pattern. And we don't decrement text index i. But we do decrement pattern index j when there is a mismatch & j value is greater than 0. In that case, i remains same. So how can worst time complexity is O(n)? It should be more than that like O(mn). For a specific value of i, we can have multiple iterations of j.

Also what is the best case scenario? Is it different than the worst case scenario? I am looking for an explanation in simple terms as I have already gone through different tutorials.

Comment: I think you need to include the pseudocode of the algorithm you're talking about. The pseudocode of the KMP algorithm on wikipedia does not have two nested loops, so it's hard to understand the specifics of your question, and it's possible you're describing the wrong algorithm (perhaps naive search rather than KMP?)

Comment: The best case for KMP is O(k) where k is the length of the search term, and happens when the string to be searched inside is of length 0. It's O(k) because the search table will still be built. The best case for KMP which results in a positive match is still O(k), and occurs when the string to be searched inside starts with the search term (it can be any length).

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to mean we have two indexes, one for text & one for pattern. I understand we don't have two loops. I have updated my question. Also understood the base case as you mentioned. Thanks @PaulHankin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

David's answer is right. You need to match j first. Then j value will be incremented & become greater than zero. After that you can decrement j value.
When you increment j, you are incrementing i also. So if you decrement j index n times, that means you have already at least incremented j index n times & which in turn means you have already incremented i index n times. So you have finished traversing the text.

So time complexity would be n negative steps + n positive steps = 2n steps. And that is O(n).

You can check this link http://www.w3spot.com/2020/07/kmp-algorithm-explained-in-plain-english.html which explains it step by step with a couple of examples, one with repetitive pattern & one with non-repetitive pattern. And it is simple enough to understand.

Comment: I understood what you guys were trying to point at. But it only got clarified when I checked the link. Concrete examples do help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

KMP never increments j without incrementing i. Hence even though there can be Theta(m) decrements of j between each increment of i, the total number of decrements of j over the course of the algorithm cannot exceed the total number of increments of j, which is equal to the number of increments of i. All are Theta(n), the worst- and best-case asymptotic running time of KMP (assuming that we're finding all matches; if not then obviously the best case is Theta(m)).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are searching string p in string s, the length for each is m and n.

Best case example, obviously O(m)

[image]

But if p isn't in s, the best case should be, p shifts right as long as possible once mismatched, the searching stage costs O(n + n/m).

[image]

The worst-case example, p shifts right very conservative once mismatched,
the searching stage costs O(n + (m-1) * (n/m)).

[image]

Where the n/m is how many mismatches will be.

And, plus the preprocessing stage, the total time costs still O(m+n) in both best and worst cases.